# Website button underline won't go away, how can I fix this?

Tags: html, css, button

I'm quite new to web development and am making a website for myself. I've come across an issue regarding buttons on my website where the text underline for a button doesn't go away. For some reason, even after applying `text-decoration: none !important;` it's still there.

**A bit of background on what I'm trying to do**

I've added two buttons that look the same, but they link to different things. This is because I want the links to change on mobile. In the CSS media query I've specified which button displays on mobile devices. The original buttons are fine, but the ones I want to use on mobile devices have a purple underline for some reason.

I'd love some help to have this sorted out because the underline makes the button look a bit odd when displayed on mobile. I've attached some images and code for one of the buttons below.

**Images:**

[image: Original Button - Displayed on desktop site]

[image: Second Button - Displayed on mobile site]

**Code:**

*This is the HTML for a pair of the buttons:*

```
 <div class="cont3_left_wrapper">
   <h2 class="hd2_1">Header Text</h2>
   <p>
     Body Text
   </p>
   <a href="#/" id="header_button_3">
     <button type="button" class="btn_chat">Let's Chat</button>
   </a>
   <a href="#/" id="header_button_3_mob">
     <button type="button" class="btn_chat_mob" onClick="location.href='contact.html'">Let's Chat</button>
   </a>
 </div>
```

*This is the CSS for the buttons:*

```
.btn_chat {
    padding: 13px 0 11px 0;
    background-color: #E84855;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 2.0407px 20.407px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    margin-top: 35px;
    width: 270px;
}

.btn_chat_mob {
    display: none;
    padding: 13px 0 11px 0;
    background-color: #E84855;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 2.0407px 20.407px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    margin-top: 35px;
    width: 270px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .btn_chat {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .btn_chat_mob {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        text-decoration: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: button inside link is not valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   .btn_chat_mob {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Your button is inside [a tag] and it has underlined as default CSS you should apply following CSS to [a tag] also it should work..

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}

a:hover {
    outline: none;
}
a:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```